# How to get the value of a datetime when form submitted

Tags: forms

I am writing a custom module in which i am declaring a $form element as #type=> 'datetime'

The code for the buildForm method is

```
 $form['timesave'] = array(
    '#type' => 'datetime',
    '#title' => $this->t('Select Date and time'),
  );
```

Now my question is how do we get the value of the field on form Submit as i have to store the value in a configuration

I have tried with

```
$form_state->getValue('timesave');
```

This is giving an array some protected methods.

Comment: For drupal 8, see [this similar question and the responses there](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/254523/how-can-i-get-the-value-a-field-type-date-using-form-state-getvalue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method `getTimeStamp()` to store the timestamp like this :

```
$form_state->getValue('timesave')->getTimeStamp();
```

Or you can use the `format()` function to store a formatting date.

```
$form_state->getValue('timesave')->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Yup.  Basically, the return value from $form_state->getValue('timesave') is a  [DrupalDateTime](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DrupalDateTime.php/class/DrupalDateTime/8.3.x) object, so any of the public methods/properties will work.

Comment: doesn't work like that... at least in Drupal 8.