# How can i get the value a field type 'date' using $form_state->getValue?

Tags: entities, datetime

I have an ajax callback on my date field that changes a particular field when user chooses a date.

Here is my code:

// INSIDE FORM_ALTER

```
$form['field_camp_scheduled_time']['widget']['#options'] = populate_scheduled_time($form, $form_state);
```

//THE METHOD

```
function populate_scheduled_time($form, $form_state){
$date = $form_state->getValue('field_camp_scheduled_date')[0];
}
```

As you can see from the method above, I'm trying to get the value of the date field. But instead of getting the date '2018-26-01', I'm getting an array:

> Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime Object (
>   [formatTranslationCache:protected] => [inputTimeRaw:protected] =>
>   [inputTimeAdjusted:protected] => [inputTimeZoneRaw:protected] =>
>   [inputTimeZoneAdjusted:protected] => [inputFormatRaw:protected] =>
>   [inputFormatAdjusted:protected] => [langcode:protected] => en
>   [errors:protected] => Array ( ) [dateTimeObject:protected] => DateTime
>   Object ( [date] => 2018-01-27 12:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3
>   [timezone] => UTC ) [stringTranslation:protected] => )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the value by using this code:

```
$date_value = $form_state->getValue('field_camp_scheduled_date')[0]['value'];

$date = new DrupalDateTime($date_value, DATETIME_STORAGE_TIMEZONE);

$value = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

`Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime` is a class - what you have is an object, not an array.

Looking at the [docs for the class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DrupalDateTime.php/class/DrupalDateTime/8.4.x), you'll find the [`prepareFormat`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Datetime%21DateTimePlus.php/function/DateTimePlus%3A%3AprepareFormat/8.4.x) method:

```
$formatted_date = $form_state->getValue('field_camp_scheduled_date')[0]
  ->prepareFormat('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: i received an ajax error @Clive♦ while trying your suggested code:

An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /lbs/node/add/campaign?ajax_form=1
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: 
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function prepareFormat() on array in C:\wamp64\www\lbs\modules\lbs_campaign\lbs_campaign.module on line 531
Call Stack
#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, creating a new date object from Bernard's answer above didn't work for me. If I cut out that step, it works fine for my webform alter.

```
$date_value = $form_state->getValue('field_camp_scheduled_date')[0]['value'];
$value = $date_value->format('Y-m-d');
```

I am running Drupal 8.9.6